# Enumeration and Plus sign together in DTD file?

Tags: java, html, xml, dtd

I have the following `.dtd` file

```
<!ELEMENT TVSCHEDULE (CHANNEL+)>
    <!ELEMENT CHANNEL (BANNER,DAY+)>
    <!ELEMENT BANNER (#PCDATA)>

    <!ELEMENT DAY (DATE,(HOLIDAY|PROGRAMSLOT+)+)>
    <!ELEMENT HOLIDAY (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT DATE (#PCDATA)>

    <!ELEMENT PROGRAMSLOT (TIME,TITLE,DESCRIPTION?)>
    <!ELEMENT TIME (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT TITLE (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT DESCRIPTION (#PCDATA)>

    <!ATTLIST TVSCHEDULE NAME CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST CHANNEL CHAN CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST PROGRAMSLOT VTR CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST TITLE RATING CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST TITLE LANGUAGE CDATA #IMPLIED>
```

I don't quite understand this line:

```
    <!ELEMENT DAY (DATE,(HOLIDAY|PROGRAMSLOT+)+)>
```

For the element `DAY`, it has `DATE` and `Enumeration`+ (either `HOLIDAY` or `PROGRAMSLOT+`), in the following statements, which one is correct?

A. `DAY` element only contains `DATE` and multiple `HOLIDAY` **only**

B. `DAY` element only contains `DATE` and multiple `PROGRAMSLOT` **only**

C. `DAY` element contains `DATE` and multiple `HOLIDAY` & `PROGRAMSLOT`

I don't understand why it can't be simplified to

```
<!ELEMENT DAY (DATE,(HOLIDAY|PROGRAMSLOT)+)>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is C:
you must have a DAY followed by a sequence in which every item in the sequence is of type HOLIDAY or a sequence of PROGRAMSLOT

Don't see the point of PROGRAMSLOT+. With

```
<!ELEMENT DAY (DATE,(HOLIDAY|PROGRAMSLOT)+)>
```

you can achieve the same flexibility.
All following examples are correct in my opinion:

```
DATE, HOLIDAY, HOLIDAY,HOLIDAY
DATE, PROGRAMSLOT, PROGRAMSLOT, PROGRAMSLOT
DATE, PROGRAMSLOT, HOLIDAY, HOLIDAY, PROGRAMSLOT
DATE, HOLIDAY, PROGRAMSLOT, HOLIDAY, PROGRAMSLOT
```

Following examples are invalid:

```
DATE, DATE // DATE can only occur once
DATE // the group of HOLIDAY OR PROGRAMLIST must occur at least once
HOLIDAY, DATE // DATE must be the first element
```